# How to pull out records based on array of values

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following structure:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.user (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_id BIGINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.conversation (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_ids BIGINT[] NOT NULL
);
```

```
INSERT INTO my_schema.user VALUES
    (1, 55555),
    (2, 77777);

INSERT INTO my_schema.conversation VALUES
    (1, '{1,2}');
```

I can pull out the `my_schema.conversation` records if I know the `my_schema.user.id` values:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.conversation
WHERE user_ids @> '{1}'
```

The above works, but I need to use `my_schema.user.tag_id` instead of `my_schema.user.id`:

How can I do this?

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nZ6i9nqh)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to join the two tables on the array values

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.user u
  JOIN my_schema.conversation c
  ON   u.id = any(c.chat_ids)
WHERE u.tag_id=55555;
```